# How to plot image none-inline in Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

There are lots of posts telling you how to display your chart/image inline. Yet once you used the magical `%pylab inline`, you have can no longer make it display image in a new window.

Is ther a magical line like `%pylab none-inline` to again make pandas display graph in new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib) is what you're looking for:

```
%matplotlib [backend]
```

when you specify `%matplotlib inline` you're opting to use Ipython's backend renderer.

Comment: Avaliable arguments to `[backend]`: gtk, gtk3, inline, nbagg, notebook, osx, qt, qt4, qt5, tk, wx

Comment: yes, after a while I found out I should search pandas display `interactive` and get the solution. Thank you for you timely reply.